# "This" keyword in C#

Tags: c#, this

Interface:

```
public interface ISubject
{
    void registerObserver(IObserver o);
    void removeObserver(IObserver o);
    void noifyObservers();
}
```

and

```
public interface IObserver
{
    void update(float temp, float humidity, float pressure);
}
```

here is class

```
public class CurrentConditionsDisplay : IObserver
    public float temperature;
    public float humidity;
    public ISubject weatherData;

    public CurrentConditionsDisplay(ISubject weatherData)
    {
        this.weatherData = weatherData;
        weatherData.registerObserver(this);
    }
}
```

The parameter of registerObserver function is IObserver but in constructor use:

```
weatherData.registerObserver(this);
```

What is "this" keyword mean ? I know "this" keyword refers to the current instance of the class but in this case what is "this" keyword mean ?

Comment: Exactly the same.  You are passing `this` as an argument to the `registerObserver` method.

Comment: Here this is instance of CurrentConditionsDisplay for which the constructor is being executed.

Comment: The `CurrentConditionsDisplay` is instantiated by its constructor which also passes itself to the `weatherData.registerObserver` method. You are able to pass `CurrentConditionsDisplay` in the method because it implements the `IObserver` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as answer also:

The `CurrentConditionsDisplay` is instantiated by its constructor which also passes itself to the `weatherData.registerObserver` method. You are able to pass `CurrentConditionsDisplay` in the method because it implements the `IObserver` interface.

Answer (score 1):

The class CurrentConditionsDisplay implements IObserver, it passes the this keyword inside it's own constructor to the weatherData.registerObserver which depends on an object instance which implements IObserver.

It can be also be a pattern of dependencyInjection of the this object into the weatherData object which waits for an instance of IObserver upon its creation.